# Mass rename files in folder

Tags: command-line, bash, rename

I have in folder ca. 400 files every file have same extension `.txt`. I want to add to every file one word or sing more so example: `stackoverflow.txt` is normal. I want to have `stackoverflowxx.txt`.

I have tried with

```
rename 's#.txt$#xx.txt#' **.txt
```

but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `rename -n 's#.txt$#xx.txt#' **.txt` (`-n` makes `rename` only print what it would do, not actually do it) and explain what you don't link about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `rename 's/\.txt$/xxx.txt/' *.txt`

It will add xxx to each txt file.